# How to count the number of "No" instances in a table with multiple "No"'s in one row

Tags: ms-access

I have a SQL statement that Selects any column where the word "No" shows up in a row. When I try to count the number of "No"'s I run in to a problem when there are multiple "No"'s in one row. It counts that as one instance (counting the row, not the "No").

```
SELECT tbl_CSRQA.ClaimantAdded, tbl_CSRQA.DocsPhoneCall, tbl_CSRQA.InsdDriverVehInfo, tbl_CSRQA.LossInfo, tbl_CSRQA.TemplateCalNotes, tbl_CSRQA.EmailtoLiab, tbl_CSRQA.ReserveScreen, tbl_CSRQA.InsNamePhone, tbl_CSRQA.Clerical, tbl_CSRQA.AdditionalSteps AS [Total Claim Errors Jan]

FROM tbl_CSRQA

WHERE tbl_CSRQA.CustomerServiceRep=[forms]![frm_CSRErrorTracking]![CSRNameCB] AND tbl_CSRQA.ClaimDate Between #1/1/2019# And #1/31/2019# AND

(tbl_CSRQA.ClaimantAdded="No" OR

tbl_CSRQA.DocsPhoneCall="No" OR

tbl_CSRQA.InsdDriverVehInfo="No" OR

tbl_CSRQA.LossInfo="No" OR

tbl_CSRQA.TemplateCalNotes="No" OR

tbl_CSRQA.EmailtoLiab="No" OR

tbl_CSRQA.ReserveScreen="No" OR

tbl_CSRQA.InsNamePhone="No" OR

tbl_CSRQA.Clerical="No" OR

tbl_CSRQA.AdditionalSteps="No");
```

Then in a report I am trying to use this;

`=DCount("[Total Claim Errors Jan]","[qry_CSRAutoTotalClaimErrorsJan]")`

The problem as I mentioned is that I want to count the number of "No"'s that appear, not the number of rows that have a "No" in it. How should I word this?

Answer (score 1):

Add below function in a standard module, then in report `=CountInstanceofNo()`

```
Option Compare Text
Public Function CountInstanceofNo() As Long
    Dim db As DAO.Database
    Dim rs As DAO.Recordset
    Dim fld As DAO.Field
    Dim counter As Long

    Set db = CurrentDb
    Set rs = db.OpenRecordset("Select ClaimantAdded, DocsPhoneCall, InsdDriverVehInfo,LossInfo,TemplateCalNotes,EmailtoLiab, ReserveScreen, InsNamePhone, Clerical, AdditionalSteps from tbl_CSRQA Where CustomerServiceRep='" & [forms]![frm_CSRErrorTracking]![CSRNameCB] & "' AND ClaimDate Between #1/1/2019# And #1/31/2019#", dbOpenDynaset)

   Do Until rs.EOF
        For Each fld In rs.Fields

                counter = counter + IIf(fld & "" = "No", 1, 0)

        Next
        rs.MoveNext
   Loop

    CountInstanceofNo = counter

    rs.Close
    Set rs = Nothing
    Set db = Nothing
End Function
```

Comment: Be careful, will probably need to apply same filter criteria to recordset as applied to the report query.

Comment: Could probably use * wildcard instead of explicitly listing all fields. And instead of hard-coding date parameters in query and code, reference textboxes on form for inputs.

Comment: @June7 Using * may give incorrect results,  as it will search for `No` in entire table and not those specific columns

Comment: Maybe, depends on what other fields hold and how many. Might be a little faster by restricting the fields. But definitely something OP can work with.

Answer (score 1):

You can use *Replace* and an old trick to build an expression in your query:

```
NoCounts: (Len([Field1] & [Field2] & … & [FieldN]) - Len(Replace([Field1] & [Field2] & … & [FieldN]), "No", ""))) / Len("No")
```

Comment: Cool! But could just use 2 instead of Len("No").

Comment: @June7: Sure - but I'm not a fan of magic numbers. Or call it a true _in-line comment_!

Comment: I think I'm going to try this. I'll report back. Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

If these were Yes/No type fields with values of -1/0, could construct a calculated field that adds all the other fields.

```
SELECT tbl_CSRQA.*,
10-Abs(ClaimantAdded + DocsPhoneCall + InsdDriverVehInfo + LossInfo + TemplateCalNotes + 
EmailtoLiab + ReserveScreen + InsNamePhone + Clerical + AdditionalSteps) AS TotNo

FROM tbl_CSRQA

WHERE CustomerServiceRep=[forms]![frm_CSRErrorTracking]![CSRNameCB] 
AND ClaimDate Between #1/1/2019# And #1/31/2019#;
```

Since these are apparently text fields, a single expression will probably be too long. Construct calculated fields with conditional expression for each field to convert to 1 or 0 then reference those calculated fields in the arithmetic expression. Alternatively, build a VBA custom function to return count of No's in each record.

Now Sum or DSum the TotNo calculated field.

Comment: Unfortunately, no, they are text boxes with "Yes", "No", "N/A". I couldn't use Yes/No because not every field applies in every row, so I needed an N/A.